# VEINS : OMNET :Model error: No nic with this ID () is registered

Tags: veins

I am new to OMNeT++. I'm using OMNeT++ 5.2.1 and SuMO 0.30, and I'm trying to parked vehicles in specific parking zone using TraCI and send some WaveShortMessage in my scenario.

When I use *TraCIDemo11p* or *MyVeinsApp* as application type (`*.node[*].applType =`), I get this error:

> Model error: No nic with this ID (27) is registered with this
>   ConnectionManager. -- in module (Veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd)
>   scenario.manager (id=6), at t=33s, event #6157

This error has occurred when the first car go parked in the parking zone at =33s and this error happens only when using this two classes: *TraCIDemo11p* or *MyVeinsApp* (in *TraCITestApp* worked fine).

Why does this error happen? Is there a way to send WSMs while using *TraCITestApp*?

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Do you have any other cars (not parked) working correctly with this setting? On your screenshot some other nodes exist.

Comment: Yes, The other cars (not parked) working correctly with this setting.
In this scenario when I use TraCITestApp.CC , The simulation was terminated without any problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that your classes don't have the behavior expected by the `applType` in the `.ned` file. Compare the .ned files of TraCITestApp and your other two to be sure