# Why does setting parked cars generate an error in OMNeT

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

In SUMO, I set up a hammock using the Manhattan model that has parked cars. Later I imported the SUMO files into VEINS and Omnet ++.

However, the error in the attached figure is shown in Omnet ++ due to the definition of parked cars. When parked cars are not defined, simulation occurs normally.

In the rou.xml file, I set the settings below for two vehicles:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
    <vehicle id="0" depart="0.00">
        <route edges="0/3to1/3 1/3to1/2 1/2to0/2 0/2to0/3"/>
        <stop parkingArea="parkingArea13" duration="3000.00"/>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="1" depart="1.00">
        <route edges="3/1to3/2 3/2to2/2 2/2to1/2 1/2to1/3 1/3to1/2"/>
        <stop parkingArea="parkingArea13" duration="3000.00"/>
    </vehicle>
```

[Error OMNeT++ image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBVNg.png)

Comment: A similar question to mine is: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951938/veins-omnet-model-error-no-nic-with-this-id-is-registered?rq=1). However no solution was given.

Comment: Which software versions (SUMO, Veins, OMNeT++) are you using?

Comment: @ChristophSommer, I am using SUMO 0.32.0, Veins 4.7.1 and OMNeT ++ 5.3.

Comment: Previously, I used the software versions described above in veins-4.7.1-i1 VM. Using the veins-5.0-i1 VM, the issue has been resolved. Probably the parked car feature was not fully compatible with the previous version of VEINS.

However, care must be taken to upgrade a project under development to the new version of VEINS. Some changes must be made to the omnetpp.ini file as described at https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/upgrading/.

Comment: Thanks for checking - I appreciate the help! I would also like to add that SUMO versions 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 are also giving problems when using Veins with parking vehicles. Newer SUMO versions seem to be working fine.

Comment: would you mind adding your comment as the correct answer? This makes it easier to find.

Comment: Even earning more points, I still can't answer my own questions.

When I submit the answer the message is displayed:

We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you, when I tried to import some parked cars into Veins.
I guess the problem lies on the syntax of writing parked cars. Your syntax

```
<stop parkingArea="parkingArea13" duration="3000.00"/>
```

appears not reliable to veins and I change the syntax to something else like the following:

```
<trip id="0" depart="0.00" from="0/3to1/3" to="4/0to3/0">
    <stop lane="0/3to1/3_0" endPos="186" duration="906" parking="true"/>
</trip>
```

Then the simulation works exactly as I want.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I followed the SUMO documentation at this link: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/ParkingArea.html. In your code, you do not define a parkingArea. Do cars stop correctly by the side of the road? Do you have a documentation link used in this code?

Comment: Firstly, I also use this parkingArea definition for parking a car, however it works badly with Veins. In my code, the car just parks at the position you defined and it works quite well. You should give it a try.

Comment: What version of VEINS are you using?

Comment: I'm using veins-5a1

Comment: You are using an Alpha version, so maybe this is what drives the differences in the definition of parked cars. I will continue with my current settings.